# Outlook 2016 not asking for password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, gmail

I have the following issue with Outlook 2016 in Windows 10:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/cannot-add-gmail-account-to-outlook-anymore/0fe79190-5556-4137-888a-1438fa6f9fe3

I am unable to add an account since the add account dialog changed.  Now Outlook doesn't ask for a password, and I get the following error:

---

Adding ************@gmail.com
(Not you?)

Something went wrong

Something went wrong and Outlook couldn’t set up your account. Please try again. If the problem continues, contact your email administrator.

[Retry]

[Change Account Type]

---

I unsuccessfully tried adding 3 or 4 other emails.  It asks for a password when trying to add a new account for my juno email, but it still doesn't work.

As suggested in the above page, in gmail I turned on 2-factor authentication and generated an app password, but Outlook doesn't ask for a password.

I have Microsoft Office 97 and Microsoft Office 365 trial installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you seriously using Microsoft Office 97? AFAIK it can't even run on Windows 10. And how about outlook 2016 on the title?

Comment: While this link may describe your situation, it is better to include the essential parts of the question here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only questions can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, ikr.  Yes, I'm using Office 97 and Outlook 2016 in Office 365.
G-Man, thx, I edited it.

Comment: why don't install a newer version, or simply use the web mail or switch to another solution like Thunderbird in case license is a problem?

Comment: I rolled back to the previous build, and now I get the old dialog and am able to add an account...  The add account wizard was added on July 28, 2017 according to this page:...  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mt465751 ...  This is how I rolled back:...  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic ...  Works for now...